# Why does Yarn ResourceManager always shutdown as I submit a job?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, wsl-2, resourcemanager

I am now learning how to build a Hadoop cluster and the first step is to try a Pseudo-Distributed cluster following the guide of https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation. And I succeeded to start yarn by call `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh` and `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh`. The output of `jps` is

[image]

However, if I submit a job, which does nothing though, the ResouceManager shutdown immediately.

`bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.1.jar wordcount input output`
The output of console is
[image: output of console]
and the log is
[image: log of resourcemanager]

The result of `strace` to ResoruceManager is

```
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
```

I struggled days and have not figured it out. Any insight advice would be welcome.

Oh I forgot to leave the version:

- Hadoop 3.3.1
- WSL: 2, Ubuntu 20.04
- Windows 11: 22518.1000

Comment: Please see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933)

Comment: Try reading the link as part of `EOFException; for more details see....`. Specifically, you seem to have a host called `master` and an IP `127.0.1.1` which should be removed... Did you edit `/etc/hosts` to create this?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your attention. I have put the `127.0.1.1 master` to hosts. Otherwise, the program died soon.

Comment: Sounds like a different problem because the Hadoop documentation states to remove `127.0.1.1` entries from the hosts file because this should always be a reference to an external IP, not a loopback address - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/ConnectionRefused . Also, I doubt your WSL2 instance hostname is called "master" since it seems to be named `YUPC-DAVELET`